# How to get database details is views in opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I am writing query in view tpl but i don't know how to get database details and execute that query in views in opencart.Here is my code

```
$query=mysql_query("select $prefixorder from opencart ");
```

Comment: Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

why bothering your self with writing queries using native functions, open cart provides some stuff for you

- First, read this article, it's great and helped me a lot [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru)
- You can now execute the query through 
  `$result = $this->db->query("write your query here");`
  You can get the number of returned rows through `$result->num_rows`, you can access the first row directly through `$result->row` which is an associative array that contains key/value pairs of the first row only, finally you can access all rows through `$result->rows` which is an array of associative arrays

Comment: Also remember that you use DB_PREFIX and should wrap your identifiers in your SQL using backticks

Comment: can it executes in views

Comment: $result = $this->db->query("write your query here"); is it works in my views i am not using model i just passing controller to view

Comment: @user3377261 Yes, you can execute it directly in the template file but only in old versions, how ever it's a very bad style, you should write the query in a model class, call that model in the controller and pass results to the template