# three dependent drop down list opencart

Tags: ajax, opencart

I want to make 3 dependents drop down list, each drop down dependent to the previous drop down, so when I select an item from first drop down , all data fetch from database and add to second drop down as item.
 I know how to do this in a normal php page using ajax, but as opencart uses MVC I don't know how can I get the selected value

Comment: I posted an answer, it's kinda long but you can escape directly to step # 2, hope it helps @Mona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Basically, you need two things:

#### (1) Handling list changes

Add an event handler to each list that gets its selected value when it changes (*the part that you already know*), detailed tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) in case someone needed it
**Just a suggestion** (for code optimization), instead of associating a separate JS function to each list and repeating the code, you can write the function once, pass it the ID of the changing list along with the ID of the depending list and use it anywhere.
Your HTML should look like

```html
<select id="list1" onchange="populateList('list1', 'list2')">
  ...
</select>

<select id="list2" onchange="populateList('list2', 'list3')">
  ...
</select>

<select id="list3">
  ...
</select>
```

and your JS

```js
function populateList(listID, depListID)
{
    // get the value of the changed list thorugh fetching the elment with ID "listID"
    var listValue = ... 
    // get the values to be set in the depending list through AJAX
    var depListValues = ...
    // populate the depending list (element with ID "depListID")
}
```

#### (2) Populating the depending list

Send the value through AJAX to the appropriate PHP function and get the values back to update the depending list (*the part you are asking for*), AJAX detailed tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)
open cart uses the front controller design patter for routing, the URL always looks like:
 `bla bla bla.bla/index.php?route=x/y/z&other parameters`, **x** = folder name that contains a set of class files, **y** = file name that contains a specific class, **z** = the function to be called in that class (if omitted, `index()` will be called)

**So the answer for your question is:**
**(Step 1)** Use the following URL in your AJAX request:
`index.php?route=common/home/populateList`
**(Step 2)** Open the file `<OC_ROOT>/catalog/controller/common/home.php` , you will find `class ControllerCommonHome`, add a new function with the name  `populateList` and add your logic there
**(Step 3)** To use the database object, I answered that previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468284/how-to-get-database-details-is-views-in-opencart/28468363#28468363)
**Note:** if you are at the admin side, there is a security token that MUST be present in all links along with the route, use that URL:
`index.php?route=common/home/populateList&token=<?php echo $this->session->data['token'] ?>` and manipulate the file at the `admin` folder not the `catalog`

---

***P.S**: Whenever the user changes the selected value in **list # i**, you should update options in **list # i + 1** and reset all the following lists **list # i + 2, list # i + 3** ..., so in your case you should always reset the third list when the first list value is changed*

---

***P.P.S**: A very good guide for OC 1.5.x => [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru) (It can also be used as a reference for OC 2.x with some modifications)*

Comment: in my view i use this  :<select id="manufacturer" name ="manufacturer">
 <option>
              Select Manufacturer
           </option>
              <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?> 
         <option>
                 <?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer']; ?> 
           </option>
        <?php } ?>
       </select>
         <select name ="type" id="type">
            echo"<option> Select Type</option>";  
         </select>
        <select id="new_select2"  >
           echo"<option> Select Serie</option>";  
         </select

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('select[name=\'manufacturer\']').on('change', function() {
url = 'index.php?route=product/pdcompatible';

 var manuf = $('select[name=manufacturer]').val();


});
    
   </script>-->

Comment: so i can show the first select options, but the problem now is that how can i work with the manuf's var in order to make the second request

Comment: can you edit your question and post that code in a formatted view because it's too hard to inspect it in comments?

Comment: how can I pass a variable from view to controller then from controller to model in order to use it in a query??

Comment: in the controller should i use this : $this->request->get

Comment: It depends on the request type, if `GET` then `$this->request->get['name']` should be used, if `POST` then `$this->request->get['name']` should be used for the parameters encoded in the link (such as the route parameter) and `$this->request->post['name']` for form data

Comment: I will update my answer if you provide more details of what you want exactly because you are requesting too many things not stated in your question